# Create a new column in an array of data fetched from mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqlfees = "SELECT feeid,occurence FROM feedetails WHERE applicablefor='$class'"; 
//fetching data
$fees_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlfees); 
//executing query
$count = mysqli_num_rows($fees_query);
if($count > 0) {
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fees_query)) {
        $feesarr[] = $fetch; //creating array
}
```

I want to add a new column to $feesarr named 'dates' along with feeid and occurence with some values

Comment: do you want to add dates( not present in table "feedetails") in $feesarr?

Comment: Can you give example with your expected output array?

Comment: yes i want to add it as an index with some values like  11/02/2015, 12/02/2015

Comment: so that i can do this
foreach($feesarr as $row) {
echo $row["occurence"];
echo $row["feeid"];
echo $row["dates"];
}

Comment: echo $row["dates"];    will output values that i will insert seprately specific to each row

Comment: where dates value ( 11/02/2015, 12/02/2015 ) comes from its hardcoded  ?

Comment: if i get this output from query
feeid       occurence
1               monthly
2                monthly

then i want to add date for each fee id  supposs for 1 its 11/5/2015 and for 2 its 14/6/2014  then output should be 

feeid       occurence      dates
1               monthly        11/5/2015
2                monthly        14/6/2014

Comment: there will be a third column dates that i will insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
     $sqlfees = "SELECT feeid,occurence FROM feedetails WHERE applicablefor='$class'"; 
     //fetching data
     $fees_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlfees); 
     //executing query
     $count = mysqli_num_rows($fees_query);
     if($count > 0) {
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($fees_query)) {
      $new_arr['date'] = $fetch['id'].'/'.other field what you want;
      $feesarr[] = array_merge($fetch, $new_arr); //creating array
    }
```